# PHP-AJAX passing input text to action url directly with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Html:

```
<form id="yourFormId" method="POST" action="/">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div id="check" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">       
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="find" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit"><div id="search" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></button>
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
  $(".form-control").on('change',function(e){
   $("#yourFormId").attr("action","/" + this.val() );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

That script doesn't work. I need an ajax solution to pass dynamically my input text to action url. How to do that?

Comment: where is the ajax?

Comment: There is no ajax. I need ajax instead of that script or fixing that script to make work. :)

Comment: you want auto complete functionality

Comment: like this https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $(".form-control").on('change',function(e){
        $("#yourFormId").attr("action","/" + $(this).val() );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: the action will be changed as you focus out the cursor from input box. or you can also use blur event instead of change event.

Comment: It is worked in this way I forgot to use jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

This code will submit your form on keyup (as soon as you stop typing)

```
var timerid;
jQuery("#yourFormId").keyup(function() {
  var form = this;
  clearTimeout(timerid);
  timerid = setTimeout(function() { form.submit(); }, 500);
});
```

In this code you intercept the form submit and change it with an ajax submit

```
$('.form-control').bind('keyup', function() { 
  $("#yourFormId").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          dataType: "html",
          url: '/url/toSubmit/to',
          data: $("#yourFormId").serialize(),,
          success: function (response) {
              //write here any code needed for handling success         }
    });
  });
});
```

To use the delay function you should use jQuery 1.4. The parameter passed to delay is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

i think u want to submit your form with ajax request with dynamic text field value.

you can use simple java script function on change or click event whatever you want or with ajax request

you simple use like this

window.location.href="/"+$(this).val();
        return false;